# Errors in C++ Hello World program

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Installed c++ in visual studio 2019 some time ago and it worked perfectly. Today when I launched I got 490 errors. This is a screenshot of what a Hello World looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/51z16.jpg

I am completely new to c++ so I dont know whats wrong, I have tried to search for the error but I could not find anything. I have tried to reinstall c++ in vs and updated vs to the newest version.

code:

```
#include <iostream> 
int main() { 
std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

its nothing wrong with the code, I think something is wrong with the librarys. For some reason I get 17 errors " cannot open file "[Some name].h" "

Comment: Please post the code, not a screenshot of the code.

Comment: `#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}`

Comment: You should edit that into your question. But there's nothing wrong with the code. What kind of errors are you getting? Probably don't need all 490, just the first dozen or so will probably do. Again, edit it into your question, don't post it as a comment.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling it? When was "some time ago"? Have you messed with the installation since then? Those errors show something seriously wrong with it.

Comment: Lol, Compilers 101: one missing file, include, define and 0.5 KiloErrors:))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalled visual studio, this worked. The problem was that it dident include C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10

Comment: Hey @VincentLagerros, I am hoping you are the coder who altered a MarchingCubes terrain creation example by Sebastien! I have a couple questions and am trying to reach you! Please can you check your facebook?